# Removing url full stop values from string "." and "。"

Tags: javascript, html, url, unicode

I'm writing a javascript regex to match string values that do not contain special characters that could be used for a url.

I've been able to match the `.` character no problem, but apparently the `。` character also works as a full stop for urls, so something like `https://google。com` entered into the Chrome url bar or as a href value would work as a normal url.

**Are there other characters, similar to `。`, that browsers interpret as url delimiters?**

Comment: Use white-listing Instead of black-listing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here are the characters that are treated as a full stop in a URI:

```
. # "Full stop", a normal period
。# "Ideographic full stop", a Japanese period
．# "Fullwidth full stop"", a period that takes up a whole character in non-monospaced fonts
｡ # "Halfwidth ideographic full stop", a Japanese period with half the width
```

I figured this out by writing a script to check every possible character, and seeing which ones acted the same as `.` in URIs:

```js
function check(char) {
   try {
     let u = new URL("https://example" + char + "com");
     return u.hostname === "example.com";
   } catch (e) {
     return false
   }
}
for (let i = 0; i < 65535; i++) {
  let char = String.fromCharCode(i);
  if (check(String.fromCharCode(i))) console.log(char, i);
}
```